# Cycle through oval/elliptical object with CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, ellipse

There's a small challenge that has taken my sleep for a few days. I didn't get success in all my attempts. To be honest, I didn't even get close.

So, basically I need to animate the object (sun) so that it travels continuously along the path of the oval. When the sun is "in the sky" (that is, on the red part of the oval shown below) it should be visible, but it should not be visible when it is "below the horizon" (the light gray part of the oval below).

[image: example]

I've seen many solutions with perfectly round objects, but none with an oval/elliptical object.

I can't use a canvas here and it'll need to be responsive, but I can use CSS3 and some JavaScript plugin.

Here is a link with my "sandbox", if you wanted to use it.
http://codepen.io/caio/pen/pvKoJx

---

Only to view the dashed, you can create an object with these properties.

```css
.path {
  border: 3px dashed black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  left: calc(50% - 295px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 165px;
  width: 590px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'cycle`...it's not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you want the sun to travel around the red path as if it is rising and setting above the text?

Comment: Yes, guys... "scroll through" or "travel" are a better definition? I'm not fluent in English, sorry.

Comment: Are you asking for the code to animate the cycle around the path? Again, it's not clear. - http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/animate-curved-path/

Comment: @Paulie_D, I need to animate the sun around the dashed path.

Comment: Then, per the SO requirements, you should show us what you have tried...even if it doesn't work however I have provided a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should take a look to this Jquery plugin : https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/jQuery-Circulate-Plugin

I think this could do the job !

Edit : the demo don't work on css-tricks.com, you need to download it.